# Sending \r in screen through ssh?

Tags: bash, ssh, printf, gnu-screen

I have been trying different ways to get this to work.

`ssh netpc screen -S minecraft -X stuff` "say Performing save/backup operations there may be lag...not really this is a test`$(printf '\r')`"

It fails to recognize the `$(printf ‘\r’)` due to some escape character that eludes me.  Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my question.

```
#!/bin/bash

say_this()
{
    screen -S $REEN -p 0 -X stuff "$1^M"
}

say_this “say Saving world”
say_this “save-off”
say_this “save-all”
...
```

This is with ssh!
    #!/bin/bash

```
say_this()
{
    # Dont forget to set NAME or whatever
    ssh -p 8989 192.168.1.101 screen -S $NAME -p 0 -X stuff \"$1^M\"
}

say_this "say test"
say_this "say !@#$%^&*()<>?This string will work!"
```